# SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne() is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory, ldap

[SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne()= NULL (image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmguH.png)

im tryin to create a custom ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider using this [guide](http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html)

but it gives me an error which says An exception of type

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Unspecified error

i tried to debug it and found out that

```
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne() is null
```

I really need your help guys, is there a way to fix this?
Any help is really appreciated! :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error most likely means that connection to AD has failed. To troubleshoot, make sure what the connection string and credentials are correct. Also check the values of *AttributeMapUsername* and *username*. Try to execute the full query directly against AD using a tool like [LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapadministrator.com).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! i will try to do what you said and sorry if my question was a bit unclear this is my first time posting here. ive been working on this problem for days.